# SQL Server : getting column values where other column all have same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem getting what I need in the example below.

My data:

```
Id      AnotherId        Status
--      ---------        ------
1           3              new
2           3              old
3           5              new
4           6              new
5           11             old
6           11             old
7           55             new
8           55             new
```

I am looking for the distinct `AnotherId` where every instance of status = 'New'

So my result would look like:

```
 5
 6
55
```

This will get me most of the way there, but I need all the 'New' status records:

```
select AnotherId
from MyData
group by AnotherId
having count(distinct Status) = 1
```

I cannot seem to get exactly what I need.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` clause :

```
select AnotherId
from table t
group by AnotherId
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'new';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I couldn't quite  figure out how to work that criteria in there.

Comment: @sabre28. . . This would return `AnotherId`s which has same `status` (i.e. `min(status) = max(status)`) and `min(status) = 'new'` will check & return `AnotherId`s which has only `status = 'new'`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're wanting is a distinct listing of Another Id with status of new, this should get you there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [AnotherId]
from [MyData]
where [Status] = 'new'
and [AnotherId] NOT IN (SELECT [AnotherId] FROM [MyData] WHERE [Status] <> 'new' AND [AnotherId] IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This would work, but there were some AnotherId's that had both new and old records, i am needing the id's will all new